# How to find which child has less than 3 child from my hierarchy of 1x3 matrix using single mySql query

Tags: mysql, multi-level, mlm

I am using 1x3 matrix to store data in mysql like below:-

ID parentID directID

1. 1    0        0 <- This is first ID (So parent is no one),
2. 2    1        1
3. 3    1        1
4. 4    -        3
5. 5    -        4
6. 6    1        1
7. 7    2        1
8. 8    2        1
9. 9    2        1
10. 10   6        1
11. 11   6        2

I am working on a MLM (multi level marketing) project with 1x3 matrix plan.

As I am using 1x3 matrix structure, I have to find the child which doesnot has 3 child below it, given the top ID as 1 (1 is directID of new ID under which it has joined). The New ID that joins the team has to assign a parentID.